# Deploying JBoss Seam 2.3 to JBoss AS 7.1.1 with Intellij IDEA 15 Ultimate

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jboss7.x, jboss-seam

I create a JBoss Seam project with a maven archtype,

```
mvn archetype:generate \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=jbosscc-seam-archetype \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=de.akquinet.jbosscc \
   -DarchetypeVersion=1.5 \
   -DarchetypeCatalog=http://seam-archetype.sourceforge.net/jbosscc-seam-archetype/1.5/archetype-catalog.xml
```

then execute

```
mvn clean packages
```

and it produces .ear file. I can deploy .ear file successfully.

My problem is to deploy with Intellij IDEA. I import the project from pom file, Intellij IDEA creates some artifacts.

When I try to deploy created ear artifact in Intellij IDEA, it fails.

How can I fix this?